# How can I use tf.Session.run() on Android?

Tags: android, tensorflow

I want to make Tensorflow predictions on the Android. I found example Tensorflow Demo app for Android. But how can I use tf.Session.run,  tf.nn.softmax and other functions?

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the Inference Library on Android, you'll see how you can load and run graphs:
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/android/src/org/tensorflow/demo/TensorFlowImageClassifier.java#L151

Here is the definition for that library:
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/android/java/org/tensorflow/contrib/android/TensorFlowInferenceInterface.java

Does that help?